# Moves in a Turing Machine

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines, finite-automata

In a Turing Machine i understand that δ(q,x) is a transition function that results in a Change in ID. What does  δ(q, Xj) =(P, y, L) mean.I understand that L stands for move left.Is P the new state and y the symbol at the tape head?Is it right?

The input string to be processed is X1X2 ... Xn,
and the present symbol under the R/W head is Xi So the ID before processing
Xi is

[image]

Before processing i understand that q is the current state and since the TM moves left the current state become p.What is y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you're right. $y$ is the symbol that was written when the tape head moved. So the statement

$$\delta(q, x_j) = (p, y, L)$$

should be read as "in state $q$, upon reading symbol $x_j$, write a $y$ on the tape, transition to state $p$, and move left".

Comment: Where is this y written?at xi? I mean the R/W Head Position when the head was in state q?

Comment: From the picture you posted it looks like that's correct. The $y$ is written where the read-write head of the machine was, at position $x_i$.

Comment: okay.It is necessary for a Turing Machine to write a symbol?

Comment: Looks like in your setup it is necessary. I think it usually is. (But if you write back the original symbol, it's as though you didn't write anything at all).

Comment: okay....Thanks.